# How to apply the fill color for different lines in amcharts 4

Tags: html, css, charts, amcharts4

Currently, I am working on plotting multiple line charts using AmCharts 4. My objective is to apply the fill color property with gradient effects to enhance the visual appeal of the charts. To accomplish this, I have written a code that is functioning smoothly. However, my next goal is to apply different gradient colors for each individual line within the charts.

By implementing distinct gradient colors for each line, I aim to create a more visually engaging representation of the data. This approach will enable viewers to differentiate between the various lines more easily, allowing for better comprehension and analysis of the charted information.

What I want to achieved is in picture. [image: Required Chart]

This is my chart code

[Current chart in CodePen](https://codepen.io/FN-12345/pen/yLQjwOp)

Code :

```js
 var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

// Set chart data
chart.data = data;

// Create axes
var dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
dateAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 50;

var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());

// Create series
function createSeries(field, name , LineColor) {
  var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
  series.dataFields.dateX = "Labels";
  series.dataFields.valueY = field;
  series.name = name;
  series.tooltipText = "[bold]{valueY}[/]";
  series.strokeWidth = 0.8;
  series.stroke = am4core.color(LineColor);
 series.tooltip.getFillFromObject = false;
 series.fillOpacity = 0.8;
 series.tooltip.background.fill = am4core.color(LineColor);
  var fillModifier = new am4core.LinearGradientModifier();
fillModifier.opacities = [0.8, 0];
fillModifier.offsets = [0, 1];
 fillModifier.gradient.rotation = 90;
 series.segments.template.fillModifier = fillModifier;
  return series;
}
createSeries("DividendReinvestment", "Dividend Reinvestment","#04275c");
createSeries("DividendDistribution", "Dividend Distribution" ,"#00FF00");
createSeries("Close", "Close",   "#800000");

// Add chart cursor

 chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
chart.cursor.lineX.disabled = true;
 chart.cursor.lineY.disabled = true;
   chart.xAxes.each(function (axis) {
     axis.renderer.grid.template.visible = false;
   });
chart.cursor.behavior = "none"

valueAxis.renderer.labels.template.fill = am4core.color("#999999");

// Customize date axis labels
   dateAxis.renderer.labels.template.fill = am4core.color("#999999");
    valueAxis.renderer.labels.template.fontSize = 12;
  dateAxis.renderer.labels.template.fontSize = 12;
   dateAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 30;
 dateAxis.tooltip.disabled = true;
 valueAxis.tooltip.disabled = true;
```

How can I achive it I have seen many links and documentation but did not find any solution